# reporoducing org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) error

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We had an incident in prod where some messages were lost. On post incident investigation they wanted to see the error occur, and see if our fix would work.

**Mission: get org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException exception.**

Here is what I have:

```
public ProducerFactory<String, MyMessage> producerFacory() {
   Map<String, Object> configProps = kafkaPropperties.buildProducerProperties();
   configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, Integer.toString(512*1024)); //I want the timeout to happen
   return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}
```

Then my publisher code:

```
public myMethod() {
   //code creating the message
   kafkaTemplate.send(myTopic, someId, message);
   Thread.sleep(60000) // This is to try and force a timeout.
}
```

Things I have tried.

- Remove Linger
- set linger to 10ms
- set linger to 60000
- set BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG small
- set BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG huge

when testing I have an app on the side that trigger a message randomly between 20 seconds and 2 minutes, and it runs for 2 hours.
One would think that a 1.4Kb message will time out with these parameters

with all this, I still cannot produce the error.
If I can prove the error, the fix can be to set Ack to 1 and maybe flush the template after .send()

Comment: we are in the process of replicating the same problem, and the only option I have in my mind, is to set a break point in the producer's Sender Thread, to block it, so that records accumulate, but are never sent. The solution to `flush` is most probably something you do not want btw, cause it will ignore `linger.ms` and most probably there will be no batching at all